# WPF run TextChanged trigger after text is done changing

Tags: c#, wpf, textchanged

I have a textbox with a `TextChanged` trigger.

However, every time the event triggers, the Min and Max value used in the method is what the value was prior to the change. For example, if Min was 5 and Max was 10, and I change Max to 1, the value that gets passed to the method is 5 and 10 for the Min and Max value, as opposed to 5 and 1.

If I change Max back to 10, the values that get passed is 5 and 1, instead of 5 and 10.

How can I fix this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Textboxes:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="minMaxValidator" Name="MinValueTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Path=Point.MinValue}">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="minMaxValidator" Name="MaxValueTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Path=Point.MaxValue}">
    </TextBox>
```

Behind:

```
private void minMaxValidator(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (Point.MinValue > Point.MaxValue)
    {
        MinValueTextBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
        MaxValueTextBox.Background = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        MinValueTextBox.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
        MaxValueTextBox.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the Binding resolved this issue. Like so:

```
    <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="minMaxValidator" Name="MinValueTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Path=Point.MinValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" TextChanged="minMaxValidator" Name="MaxValueTextBox"
             Text="{Binding Path=Point.MaxValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    </TextBox>
```

Comment: Yep that could help, however there are plenty of usercontrol that does that for you. An example could be the NumeriUpAndDown from Mahapps , that is a free nuget package with a lot of styled control with also this type of feature (it also prevent the user to insert text)